# Update/Import data to Odoo db from a python list

Tags: database, odoo

TLDR : i get data from a external database that i work on using python and return a list of tuples and i don't know how i can import this list to Odoo.

I request data to an external database and do some work on it before having my final result which correspond to a model i have created in Odoo. the result is a list of tuple and each tuple correspond to a single record.
Now that I have this record I want to insert it into Odoo to put it into my view for the user but don't know how to do that.

At first i tried with sql constraint and a manual import of a CSV file but the constraint don't let the import work if the constraint is triggered.

I don't really know where to go from here and I am a bit lost.

Comment: Have you tried to use the [external API](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/17.0/developer/reference/external_api.html)? Why did you combine a sql constraint with the CSV import?

Comment: @CZoellner i combined sql constraint with csv import because when i imported the data without it, data would duplicate. for the external API it seems like it could be my solution, I will try it right now

Comment: Just add an external id (column name `id`) to your csv or xlsx. That will be an unique named identifier for you imported records, which will open up the update feature and obviously not creating duplicates. An external ID in Odoo always consists of two parts: module_name and name divided by a dot `.`. For example if you have another system, let me call it "Not Odoo",  and a unique ID on the system and you have a model name in Odoo, let me call it "my_model", i would generate the external id as "not_odoo.my_model_1" where `1` is obviously the unique db id from "Not Odoo" system.